# Does the C++ standard guarantee that uniform initialization is exception-safe?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, c++17, uniform-initialization

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() { cout << "A" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "~A" << endl; }
};

A Ok() { return {}; }
A NotOk() { throw "NotOk"; }

struct B
{
    A a1;
    A a2;
};

void f(B) {}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        f({ Ok(), NotOk() });
    }
    catch (...)
    {}
}
```

`vc++` and `clang` output:

```
A
~A
```

While `gcc` outputs:

```
A
```

It seems a serious bug of GCC.

For reference, see [GCC bug 66139](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66139) and ["A serious bug in GCC" by Andrzej Krzemieński](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/a-serious-bug-in-gcc/).

I just wonder:

**Does the C++ standard guarantee that uniform initialization is exception-safe?**

Comment: What version(s) of GCC exhibit this?

Comment: @einpoklum all.

Comment: I don't think that exception safety is an issue here. Barring 1) an immediate application exit, via exit(), 2) undefined behavior, -- if an object gets constructed in automatic scope, it must be destroyed when execution leaves its scope. This is fundamental to C++. This is a compiler bug.

Comment: First I thought it may be some stupid optimization, since static analysis figures out the program exits immediately on that catch-all handler. But no, it's a compiler bug. [A very major and horrible bug](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4a7b98a334e8625).

Comment: I added a copy constructor that logs itself, and changed to offending sequence to `A a=Ok(); f({ a, NotOk() });`. I logged the copy constructor getting invoked, during construction of the parameter to the function call, and the destructor getting invoked for the instance of `a` in local scope, but no destructor getting invoked for the copy-constructed instance.

Comment: So you have a blog that says it's a bug, and a gcc bug report that says and confirms it as a bug... but then you have a question asking if it's a bug?

Comment: @StoryTeller: [Your same code but also running clang for comparison](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ced225e4314f6041)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems so:

Curiously found in §6.6/2 Jump Statements [stmt.jump] of all places (N4618):

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic
>   storage duration (3.7.3) that have been constructed in that scope are
>   destroyed in the reverse order of their construction. [ Note: For
>   temporaries, see 12.2. —end note ] Transfer out of a loop, out of a
>   block, or back past an initialized variable with automatic storage
>   duration involves the destruction of objects with automatic storage
>   duration that are in scope at the point transferred from but not at
>   the point transferred to. (See 6.7 for transfers into blocks). [ Note:
>   However, the program can be terminated (by calling `std::exit()` or
>   `std::abort()` (18.5), for example) without destroying class objects
>   with automatic storage duration. —end note ]

I think the emphasis here is on the "(however accomplished)" part. This includes an exception (but excludes things that cause a `std::terminate`).

---

#### EDIT

I think a better reference is §15.2/3 Constructors and destructors [except.ctor] (**emphasis** mine):

> If the **initialization** or destruction of an object other than by
>   delegating constructor is terminated by an exception, **the destructor
>   is invoked for each of the object’s direct subobjects** and, for a
>   complete object, virtual base class subobjects, whose initialization
>   has completed (8.6) and whose destructor has not yet begun execution,
>   except that in the case of destruction, the variant members of a
>   union-like class are not destroyed. The subobjects are destroyed in
>   the reverse order of the completion of their construction. Such
>   destruction is sequenced before entering a handler of the
>   *function-try-block* of the constructor or destructor, if any.

This would include aggregate initialization (which I learned today can be called *non-vacuous initialization*)

...and for objects with constructors we can cite §12.6.2/12 [class.base.init](**emphasis** mine):

> In a non-delegating constructor, the destructor for each potentially
>   constructed subobject of class type is potentially invoked (12.4). [
>   Note: **This provision ensures that destructors can be called for
>   fully-constructed subobjects in case an exception is thrown** (15.2).
>   —end note ]

Comment: And now I'm reviewing in my head all the programs I've written that may jeopardize the system on uncaught exception and failed asserts...

Comment: @YSC: Well, a failed assertion should not jeapordise the system. If an assertion fails because of this bug and a critical system is shut down and restarted instead of providing random behaviour, then I'd say the assertion has indeed performed the job it was designed to perform. That's exactly why you put it there - protect system integrity and data consistency in the face of terrible bugs.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm worried about _"[ Note: However, the program can be terminated (by calling std::exit() or std::abort() (18.5), for example) without destroying class objects with automatic storage duration. —end note ]"_

Comment: @YSC: Ah, I think I misunderstood your comment. However, in that case failed assertions should be even less of a concern, no? In fact, that's pretty much the reason you use `assert` or `exit` or `abort`; you don't *want* any more code to executed because you've detected a bug or an emergency of some kind, and that includes code in destructors. My point is: in certain situations in C++, it is correct and desirable to *not* execute destructors of local objects and instead quit immediately. Of course, this terrible GCC bug isn't one of them.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes I agree. I just never though about it.